# Concatenating two queries bases on a foreign key

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm (at least trying) to implement `Repository pattern` in my .NET C# project so when I need to communicate with the database I us something like this:

```
IList<Sole> soles = SoleService.All().ToList();
```

As the name of the method called from the service suggest with the query above I get all records form `Sole` table. I don't want and I think this is the right way to implement this pattern, to keep too much custom logic in my service. What I mean is that I only want to keep the `All()` method and each modification of the result to be made outside the service methods.

The current problem is this. I have entity `Sole` and entity `SoleColor`. `SoleColor` has a foreign key column `SoleID` making the relation between the two tables. Right now for those two entities I can call only `All()` method :

```
var soleColors = SoleColorService.All();
var soles = SoleService.All();
```

But here I need some customization in the form of selecting only those rows from `Sole` that are related with the `SoleColor` entity. In other words only end up with a list of only those rows from `Sole` where Sole.ID can be found as a foreign key in `SoleColor` SoleID foreign key.

Right now I'm a bit confused - it's been a while since I last used plain SQL synthax. I think this is easily achieved using SQL and JOIN. But when LINQ is involved and my experience so far tells me that I need those two queries :

```
var soleColors = SoleColorService.All();
var soles = SoleService.All();
```

And then make some kind of JOIN/UNION to filter only the results I need.

So which tools I need to use in this kind of situation cause it's not the only place I'm gonna need this and I want to learn to do it myself and of course to do it in this current situation?

Comment: Are you using **the** LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework? Anyway, as you noticed, you can either look up the [IQueryable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb534644.aspx) or [IEnumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx), or - when using EF - use navigation properties. :)

Comment: Sorry I even didn't thought this must be an issue. I'm using ADO.NET EX - Code First approach.

Comment: I'm just clarifying, the LINQ To SQL is an *older*, while Entity Framework (using LINQ To Entities) is a tad newer, while both work a little bit different.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed us your Sole and SoleColor objects... you might be missing things there. With LINQ you should be able to go `SoleColorService.All().Where(s => s.SoleId.HasValue)` as an example

Comment: > In the cases where you need mutable queries from your repository, but still want the benefit of interchanging OR mappers if needed, IQueryable is a powerful tool. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573658/repository-pattern-and-linq-to-sql

Comment: @Felix I think you can upgrade this to an answer.

Comment: Ok, maybe i didn't make myself clear - in SoleColor entity `SoleId` is required.So I don't think `SoleColorService.All().Where(s => s.SoleId.HasValue)` will solve my problem. I need to find a way to determine which `ID`'s in `Sole` Entity are reprsented in `SoleColor` as `SoleID` FK and when I `SoleService.All()` to show only these record which `ID` is used in `SoleColor` - `SoldeId` .

Answer (score 1):

After your last comment I think this is what you're looking for:

```
from s in SoleService.All()
join sc in SoleColorService.All() on s.ID equals sc.SoleID
select s
```

But this only works if both repositories have the same context instance. If not, you have to do it in two steps:

```
var ids = SoleColorService.All().Select(sc => sc.SoleID).ToArray();
var soles = SoleService.All().Where(s => ids.Contains(s.ID));
```

I'm a bit suspicious though about the static `All()` methods. They suggest that you use static contexts, which is considered bad practice. Further I wonder about the associations. By the sound of the words I'd expect `Sole` to have a `SoleColor`, i.e. Sole to have a SoleColorId FK.

Comment: I get an error - `The value can not be null` - even though I can't see what exactly takes null value. I tried both examples though.

Comment: Is any of these `SoleId`s nullable?

Comment: No I thought the same be it's of type `long` not `long?` and in the database it is marked as `NOT NULL`

Comment: OK, I need to see the code where this exception occurs. Maybe you can add it to your post and mark the line that throws the exception.

Comment: I'm using the second solution. First on this line : `var soles = SoleService.All().Where(s => ids.Contains(s => s.SoleID));` This - `(s => s.SoleID)` is marked as error and the error is - `Cannot convert lambda expression to type long because it is not a delegate type`. I tried to change it with - `ids.Contains(s.ID)` - not sure why you wrote - `s.SoleID`. `SoleID` is the FK and `s` has simply `ID` as far as I understand the meaning of the code. So far what do you think?

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure why you edited to `Contains(s.SoleID)` s has `ID` and even if I try with `s.SoleID` it just get's makred as an error. However the compile error is here - `cboSole.SetDataSource(soles.ToList());`. `cboSole` is a ComboBox and I have custom method for attaching the data source the full error is :`[System.ArgumentNullException] = {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: keySelector"}`

Comment: Look, I don't know your field names, but the answer should suggest what you can do. The ComboBox problem is a different problem altogether. I think you better start a new question for it. The point here is whether the queries produce the data you expect.